# Cannot resize OS X startup parting (both diskutil and Disk Utility GUI freeze)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, filesystem

I'm trying to shrink my Yosemite partition and create a new one.

Trouble is that the Disk Utility gets stuck "Preparing to partition disk" (same thing when run in recovery), and diskutil in a recovery terminal freezes the moment I enter the diskutil command.

I've read the diskutil manual, done Google searches, and tried the various solutions (such as verify disk).

What should I do?

If you need more info, let me.

(I have a Boot Camp partition with Windows 10).

Comment: I've edited the tags - you might explain what OS is running to provide Disk Utility? If you start in Internet Recovery or Recovery HD, you will have better luck preventing open files from halting a resize operation. The downside is you won't have good logging if a hardware error is causing the delay / failure.

Comment: Depending on your disk config your request will probably break Boot Camp. Please add the output of `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list`.